# Testing multiple simultaneous sessions with mocha-chai superagent

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mocha.js, superagent, chai-http

I am trying to write tests for multiple socket connections, which I need to have **multiple sessions (simultaneously)** for since they are identified by session ID on the server side...

In the example below *client1* will connect and the handshake will be passed the  cookie with session id so i can use *express-socket.io-session* to get the session data for that user....

The problem i'm running into is when i want to connect a second socket, the handshake data passed through is obviously going to be the same as the first socket.

I can't just send a logout request and change user because i'm trying to test multiplayer functionality.

```
var agent = chai.request.agent(app)

describe("authentication", function () {
    it('login as user', function (done) {
        agent
            .post('/login')
            .send({
                username: username,
                password: password
            })
            .then(function (res) {
                expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                expect(res).to.have.cookie('connect.sid');
                done()
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                done(err)
            })
    });

})


describe("socket tests", function () {
    var client1, client2;

    it('can connect to socket', function (done) {
        client1 = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/", options);
        client1.on('connect', () => {
            done();
        })
    });

    it('can connect second user to socket', function (done) {
        client2 = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/", options);
        client2.on('connect', () => {
            done();
        })
    });
})
```